# enforce coverage at file level in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jacoco

Is there any way to enforce coverage at file level, using jacoco and jenkins?

I don't generally advocate for 100% coverage, but in certain files I'd love to keep them > 95%, while other files I'm happy with 70%. However I didn't find a way to  make it automatically break the build if file A is < 95 OR the average is below 70.

I'm thinking in parsing the jacoco.xml in groovy, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define thresholds

- [Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin) has configuration options
- [Ant task](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) `report` has element `check`
- [Maven plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) has `check` goal
- [Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_violation_rules) has `JacocoCoverageVerification` task

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you very much. I don't know how I missed it in Jenkins plugin documentation, I deserve a RTFM!